# R Markdown Hashtag Hover Output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create an R-Markdown document and for some reason on all headers of the document denoted by `###` etc..., when I knit to html and hover over each word, an underlined hashtag appears. Is there a way to get rid of this in the output? As an example, below is the standards cars summary.

I tested on another machine and had no issues with the output. Could I be missing a certain package? I'm currently using Rstudio version 1.3.1093 and R version 4.0.3 on the PC that is not showing the correct output.

Thank you in advance[image]

[image]

Comment: there is a yaml option for this, I just can't remember it, try `anchor_links: false` in the yaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new feature of the latest release of `rmarkdown` you can disable it by adding `anchor_sections: FALSE` to the yaml header, it's documented in the [release notes](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/releases/tag/v2.5)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the CSS that is putting that `#` in there in the first place. Doing this means there will only be a cosmetic change, so no unintended side-effects.

Place a set of style tags after the YAML header and set the content of the `a.anchor-section::before` element to `''`.

```
<style>
  a.anchor-section::before {
    content: '';
  }
</style>
```

If you use right-click your output html document and click *inspect element* you can dive into the CSS that controls each element - the default in this case is `a.anchor-section::before {content: '#';}`.

You probably also want to add this too

```
a.anchor-section {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```